# Messing with Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, async-await, future

I want to make a non-blocking web service for a REST API.

This web service should return a Json that look like this:

```
[{"elementA": [{"id:" "1", "Type": "a", "elements":[{"idOfElement":"3", "typeOfElement": "4", "otherData": "Some"}]}]}]
```

I am using Async/Await, but the problem is that every function does its return before the future is resolved, so the collection of an element is returned empty.

Here is an example of one function:

```
val sensorPositionParameters: InputSensorPositionRequestValues = {
  parseSensorPositionInput(sensorRequest)
}
var sensorPositionRequestDeviceSequence: LinearSeq[SensorPositionRequestDevice] = {
  LinearSeq[SensorPositionRequestDevice]()
}
async {
  try {
    sensorPositionParameters.deviceMacAddress.foreach(
      // TODO: Remove the blocking result
      deviceMacAddress => Await.result(async {
        val sensorHubs = await(
          SensorHubRepository.sensorHubsFromDeviceMacAddress(deviceMacAddress)
        )
        val processedSensorHubs = await(processSensorHubs(sensorHubs))
        sensorPositionRequestDeviceSequence = sensorPositionRequestDeviceSequence :+
          SensorPositionRequestDevice(deviceMacAddress, processedSensorHubs)
      }, Duration.Inf)
    )
    parseSensorPositionOutput(sensorPositionRequestDeviceSequence)
  }
  catch {
    case ex: Exception => s"$unexpectedSensorPositionErrorPrefix ${ex.getMessage}"
    case _: Throwable => s"$unexpectedSensorPositionError"
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added an `Await.result` to my code, but I want to avoid blocking all I can.

Sorry for my bad English, and if my question is unclear I will edit it to improve it.

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should chain all calls inside your foreach loop:

```
val futures = sensorPositionParameters.deviceMacAddress.map (deviceMacAddress=>
  for(
    sensorHubs <-   SensorHubRepository.sensorHubsFromDeviceMacAddress(deviceMacAddress);
    processedSensorHubs <- processSensorHubs(sensorHubs)
  ) yield processedSensorHubs
)
```

This will give you the list of futures. Then you need to convert this list of futures to Future of list with Future.sequence(futures).

Of course, it is not a complete solution. I hope you now got a hint how to avoid usages of await function

Comment: You can use [`Future.traverse(addresses)(...)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@traverse[A,B,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]]%28in:M[A]%29%28fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[B]%29%28implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]) instead of `Future.sequence(addresses.map(...))`

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you!!
This was the approach that I took, and it worked flawlessly!